# how to keep 'Camel-kafka's Consumer running in JMeter load testing?

Tags: java, jmeter, apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have built a kafka consumer using camel through JAVA DSL as :

```
from(endpoint).process(new Processor() {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exc) throws Exception {

        setMessageBeanInExchange(exc);
    }                       
}).bean(Service.class);
```

Under the class's main method I just create new object to start consuming the messages from kafka. In local JVM it keeps running forever without even providing Thread.sleep().

While testing the same class under JMeter it instantly exits and does not consume messages. need help how I can keep it running in JMeter until all my messages are consumed to monitor the time and various logs.